# excel: delete entire row if there is a matched value (img attached)

Tags: excel

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKkGp.jpg

In the image above, I am trying to target all rows that have the value "ratings_users". For all rows that match this value, I want to just delete the entire row. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Could that value appear in multiple columns or just that one? If it is just one column, have you tried using an AutoFilter to show just the rows that have ratings_user in that column, and then manually deleting the rows? Not sure what your context is, but that could be a simple way :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro like this:

```
Sub DeleteRatingsUsers()

maxRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To maxRow
    If (StrComp(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Text, "ratings_users", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next

End Sub
```